# Blender.desktop does not launch Blender 2.79b

Tags: 20.04, blender

This is probably pretty noob stuff but I'm stuck and all the tutorials led me to the same result.

I have Blender 2.82 from the Ubuntu Software Store running on 20.04 Focal Fossa just fine.
But I also need Blender 2.79b, so [downloaded that from Blender site](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79b-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2) and extracted into:
`/home/name/snap/blender279b`

From there edited a .desktop shortcut file and placed in my user desktop folder (also tried placing it in `/home/name/.local/share/applications` to no avail)

File contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blender
Exec=/home/name/snap/blender279b %f
Icon=/home/name/snap/blender279b
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;3DGraphics;
MimeType=application/x-blender;
```

However, it does not open Blender ("Allow executing file as program" is ticked).
The "Allow launching" option is not present in the right-click menu.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if the `Exec=` line pointed to an executable rather than to a folder (you indicated you extracted into /home/name/snap/blender279b, and at the same time you specify that as the executable)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257151/blender-desktop-file-does-not-have-allow-launching-as-an-option-when-right-cl/1257182#1257182

Comment: That was obvious and I missed it, changed that line, but still no show.
`Exec=/home/name/snap/blender279b/blender %f`

Comment: Does blender2.79 run on your machine, it may be linked to older lib versions you don't have? In a terminal `cd /home/name/snap/blender279b && blender`

Comment: That code, despite pointing to the correct Blender 2.279b dir, starts the other, more recent copy of Blender 2.82 installed via Ubuntu Software Store!

Comment: Solved by just embracing the change and leaping to Blender 2.9, via Ubuntu Software Center. Dropped older versions. Thanks for your help and suggestions.